# Load and Parse a JSON file in local system using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am new to scripting languages. I have googled for loading and parsing the JSON file using jQuery. I have taken the help of those links that I got from Stack Overflow.

I have this JSON file named `new.json` .

```
 { "a": [
           {"name":"avc"},
           {"name":"Anna"},
           {"name":"Peter"},
           {"Folder": "ABC", "name":[
           {"name":"John"},
           {"name":"Anna"},
           {"Folder":"XYZ", "name":[ 

                     {"name":"fdgh"},
                     {"name":"hdfghh"},
                     {"Folder":"JKL", "name":[ 

                                {"name":"gdfgdfgggggg"},
                                {"name":"hddddddddddddddddddddddddddddh"},  
                                {"Folder":"PQR", "name":[ 

                                        {"name":"gddddddg"},
                                        {"name":"ddhh"}

                                       ]
                                  }
                             ]
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              }
          ]
      }
```

And this is my code jQuery/JavaScript code to load the `new.json` file. I have written my Code inside the `<script>` tag.

```
     <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"     src="C:\Users\Girish\Desktop\new.json"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       var out="<ul>"; 
       var j=0;

       function functionName(event) {
             $('li[id^="foo"]').click(function(e){ 
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        var x = $(this).last().find(' > ul').clone().find('ul').remove().end();
                        $('#list').html(x);
                        $("#list .hide").show();
             });
         }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('li[id^="foo"]').each(function() {
                $(this).on('click', {param: this.id}, functionName);
         }); 
    });

    function read(obj){

        for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
        {
            if(obj[i].Folder)
            {
               var name = "foo"+ ++j;
               var name2 = "<li id=" + name + ">";
               out = out+ name2 + obj[i].Folder + "<ul>";

               document.getElementById("tree").innerHTML = out;

               read(obj[i].name);
               out=out+"</ul></li></ul>";
            }
            else
            {
                 var name2 = "<li class=\"hide\">";
                 out = out+ name2 + obj[i].name;
                 document.getElementById("tree").innerHTML = out;
                 out=out+"</li>";
            }
          }
      }

     function show()
     {
       //read(a)
        var myItems;

        $.getJSON('new.json', function(data) {
        myItems = data.a;
        read(myItems)
     });

   }

 </script>
```

and this is `<body>` tag.

```
  </div>
  <div id="list"></div>
```

When I am running this code on Google Chrome. It is giving this error

`jquery-3.1.0.js:9392` `XMLHttpRequest` cannot load `file:///C:/Users/Girish/Desktop/new.json`. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: `http`, data, chrome, chrome-extension, `https`, chrome-extension-resource. on console. I have googled this error, I have found some links that says  that run the same file on Mozilla Firefox.

The same code I am running on Mozilla Firefox, It is not giving any error. It is showing Items in `#tree` div. but when I am clicking on any item in `tree` div. It is not showing its child elements in `#list` div.

**Now I want to load the json file on both `Chrome` and `Firefox`. How can I fix the above error?**

**Why child items are not showing in `list` div when clicking on any item in `tree` div?**

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum, please post a separate question for your 2nd issue.

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with JQuery. You simply can't access local files if you're running a web page locally (with `file:///` at the beginning of the URL). It violates the security model of locally run pages.

The error you're receiving is related to something called CORS (cross origin resource sharing) and is a widely used security mechanism to only allow client-side browser applications on the same domain to access resources or APIs. Anything outside the trusted CORS policy gets rejected. In the case of local web pages, files are considered to be outside your origin; Your browser essentially considers your hard drive to be on a different domain. Otherwise, malicious scripts would be able to easily access your local files by simply guessing paths to access.

To fix this, you need to use some kind of development server (or full blown web server) so that your page can be locally hosted. Then you can access your page via `http://localhost/` or your local IP address, usually `http://127.0.0.1/`.

Some examples of development servers that can host static files:

- [Fenix Web Server](http://fenixwebserver.com/) looks like a good option for static hosting
- If you have Python installed `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` will start a server on `http://localhost:8000/` in whatever folder you start it in
- [Mongoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose) seems to have nice web-based management console

Basically any search for `static web server` (with your operating system) should find a lot of simple options.

Comment: Can we do it through some code? What I want to do is, I will send this **new.json** file and my html page named **page.html** to many users. and whem they open **page.html**, then **new.json**. User can run this file on any browser.  User may or may not have these setting for chrome. Then how we can achieve this.

Comment: Why the child element is not showing in **#list** div? Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: Why don't you host this page online so that anyone involved can access it over the web? Web pages are not designed to act like local apps.